# Probability USC Problem Error?

Tags: probability

A person rolls four fair six-sided die. What is the probability that the person
rolls exactly one 1 and exactly one 2?

This is rather a simple probability problem, but I scored incorrectly for some reason. I first discerned how many total possibilities there were which was $\frac{1}{6^4}$. I then figured out how many checked out. I did $\frac{(1*1*4*4)(4!)}{6^4}$; one way to choose 1, one way to choose 2, and since there can only be exactly one of 1 and 2, the other two die must be 4. I then multiplied by 4! for 24 different arrangements. I resulted in an answer of $\frac{8}{27}$ but the answer is $\frac{4}{27}$.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: You are neglecting the symmetry between the two uncertain rolls.  Interchanging those two does not change your list so you must divide by $2$.

Comment: Don't you need to consider both of the uncertain rolls?

Comment: To avoid dealing with symmetries, I think it is easier to reason as:  There are four places to put the $1$, then three to put the $2$, then sixteen ways to populate the other two slots.  Thus there are $4\times 3\times 2^4$ possible rolls that pass the test.  As there are $6^4=2^4\times 3^4$ possible rolls in total, the answer is the quotient $\frac {4\times 3\times 2^4}{2^4\times 3^4}=\frac 4{3^3}$.

Comment: Of course you do, but in your way of counting you consider them twice.

Comment: To be clear:  you consider the roll $(1,2,3,5)$ as itself and again as a permutation of $(1,2,5,3)$.  Mind you, it is true that the roll $(1,2,3,3)$ is not paired with anything else under the symmetry I mentioned so it isn't clear to me why you are exactly odd by a factor of $2$.  Perhaps there are multiple errors.  In any case, I strongly recomment the reasoning given in my earler comment.

Comment: Oh, when you multiplied by $4!$ you effectively paired the $(1,2,3,3)$ with some (non-existent) other roll.  That is, one permutation contained in $4!$ is the one that keeps the first two in place and switches the last two,  Of course that permutation has no effect on the given roll, but you count it twice anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Multinomial probability.** Consider three kinds of outcomes in each of $n=4$ trials:  $1$'s, $2$'s, and
'something else', with probabilities $(1/6), (1.6),$ and $(4/6),$ respectively.

$$P(\text{One 1 and One 2}) = {4 \choose {1,1,2}}(1/6)^1(1/6)^1(4/6)^2
= \frac{4!}{1!\cdot 1!\cdot 2!}\frac{4^2}{6^4} = \frac{4}{27} = 0.1481481.$$

**Simulation.** In R statistical software we simulate the 4-roll experiment
a million times. At the end, the vector `event` has a million `TRUE`s and `FALSE`s; the mean of such a logical vector is its proportion of `TRUE`s.
With a million iterations, the result `0.148` should be accurate to at least two decimal places (in this particular case, three places).

```
set.seed(625)  # for exact same simulation, retain this; omit for fresh simulation
m = 10^6; event = logical(m)
for(i in 1:m){
  s = sample(1:6, 4, repl=T)
  event[i] = (sum(s==1)==1) & (sum(s==2)==1) 
  }
mean(event)
## 0.147672           # aprx probability 'One 1 and One 2'
2*sd(event)/sqrt(m)
## 0.0007095495       # 95% margin of simulation error
```

*Note:* Second, more efficient, logically equivalent simulation. It uses
pseudorandom numbers in exactly the same way as did the first simulation, so it gets
exactly the same result starting with the same seed.

```
set.seed(625) 
m = 10^6;  die = c(1, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0)  # 1=1, 10=2, 0=Else
s = replicate( m, sum(sample(die, 4, repl=T)) )
mean(s==11)
## 0.147672
```